# Type '{}[]' is not assignable to type 'ShoppingCartItem[]'

Tags: angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore

Im trying to solve this problem for long time now .The compiler shows error but the program still runs correctly if i recompile. Help to get ride of the error.
**Error :**

> Type '{}[]' is not assignable to type 'ShoppingCartItem[]'.   Type
>   '{}' is not assignable to type 'ShoppingCartItem'.
>       Property 'product' is missing in type '{}'.

**My Service.ts**
`async getCart():Promise<Observable<ShoppingCarts>>{
    let cartId = await localStorage.getItem('cartId')
    return this.shoppingCartCollection.doc(cartId).collection('items').valueChanges()
    .map(data => new ShoppingCarts(data)) 
  }`

**My class and interface**

```
    export interface ShoppingCartItem{
    product:Product;
    quantity:number;
}
export class ShoppingCarts{
    constructor(public shoppingItems:Array<ShoppingCartItem>){}
    get getProducts(){
        return this.shoppingItems.filter(element => (element.quantity != 0));
    }
    get totalItemsCount(){
        let count = 0;
        for (let product of this.shoppingItems)
            count += product.quantity
        return count;
    }
}
```

**Product Interface**

```
export interface Product {
    title:string,
    price:number,
    $key:string,
    category:string,
    imageUrl:string
};
```

Object I get is :

```
(5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0:product:{$key: "02loEh33W51bSkfBXgqN", category: "Bread", imageUrl: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1d/Bagel-Plain-Alt.jpg", price: 2.4, title: "Bagel Bread"}
quantity:2
__proto__:Object
1:product:{$key: "1xrkYBMg4GYh4JKe8wpp", category: "Fruits", imageUrl: "http://www.picserver.org/pictures/apple01-lg.jpg", price: 5, title: "Apple"}
quantity:4
__proto__:Object
2:
product:{$key: "3frhYw5TlyGnnwM9opb5", category: "Fruits", imageUrl: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c4/Orange-Fruit-Pieces.jpg", price: 4.5, title: "Orange"}
quantity:1
__proto__:Object
3:{product: {…}, quantity: 0}
4:{product: {…}, quantity: 1}
length:5
```

Comment: Which line/expression exactly is the compiler complaining about?

Comment: can you try `return this.shoppingCartCollection.doc(cartId).collection<ShoppingCartItem>('items').valueChanges()`

Answer (score 0):

In lack of the exact line where the error occures, or the part of code, I reproduced the error with this code:

```
interface ShoppingCartItem {
  product: string;
}

class ShoppingCart implements ShoppingCartItem {
  product: string; 
}

const t: ShoppingCartItem[] = [{}]; // TS2322 [..]  Property 'product' is missing in type '{}'
```

To solve this, just type cast the empty object:

```
const t: ShoppingCartItem[] = [{} as ShoppingCartItem];
```

Comment: Hello ... thank you for the help .The error is produced in the map function of the service ,where i return new ShoppingCartItem Object and pass the data.

Comment: Ah, so then type cast the constructor parameter like this: `.map(data => new ShoppingCarts(data as ShoppingCartItem[]))` as the data has no concrete type at this point.